# Programmatically set android:layout_centerHorizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, centering, android-relativelayout

In xml you can do the following:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ...
/>
```

How would I, when I have the instance of `TextView`, do this programmatically?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You should use the `addRule` method of the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class.

```
layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
mTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: My browser didn't show yours when I added mine. You posted yours first so you get my vote.

Comment: note to set if FALSE, you have to create a new layoutParams from scratch without CENTER_HORIZONTAL and then assign it

Comment: @max4ever I think you could just use removeRule()

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you have a TextView called stored in a variable tv:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Be sure to check `lp`. `getLayoutParams` can return null

Answer (score 1):

After 10 minutes of fighting I found how to do it in Kotlin:

N.B. - I am using view binding

```
val centerHorizontal = binding.tvOccupantName.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
centerVertical.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
binding.tvOccupantName.layoutParams = centerHorizontal
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `txtPhone` is the textview that we are trying to place it center in horizontal.

If you are using Java then use the following code,

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txtPhone.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
txtPhone.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

If you are using Kotlin then use the following code,

```
val layoutParams = txtPhone.getLayoutParams() as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
txtPhone.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
```